# select the two latest rows for each user to get the difference of a column (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with a mysql query. I have a table with an ID (autoincrement), an user ID, a value and the time in seconds. Now I want to get the difference of the two lowest values for each user, but don't know how to do it :(

I have the following table:

```
id   |  uid  | myvalue |  thetime
-----+-------+---------+-----------
13   |   1   |   120   | 1389287800
14   |   2   |   100   | 1389287810
15   |   3   |   110   | 1389287820
16   |   2   |    80   | 1389287830
17   |   4   |   100   | 1389287840
18   |   1   |   110   | 1389287850
19   |   3   |   105   | 1389287860
20   |   1   |   100   | 1389287870
```

I want to have the following result:

```
uid  | difference      --> Order by difference
-----+------------
 2   |     20
 1   |     10
 3   |      5
```

It would be great, if someone is out to help me. Thank's a lot!!

Comment: What is the Sql you have written till now you can perform arithemtic operations correct?

Comment: In have written douzens of querys, but none of them shows the result. Latest example: SELECT *, t1.myvalue - t2.myvalue AS difference FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 on t1.myvalue > t2.myvalue AND t1.uid = t2.uid GROUP BY t1.uid ORDER BY t2.myvalue DESC, t2.thetime DESC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to improve on this, but this is basically how you do this. you can use a self-join

```
SELECT uid, MAX(myvalue)-MIN(myvalue) AS diff FROM
    (SELECT a.* FROM tablename AS a
        LEFT JOIN tablename AS a2
            ON a.uid=a2.uid AND a.myvalue<=a2.myvalue
        GROUP BY uid,myvalue
        HAVING COUNT(*)<=2
    ) a
GROUP BY uid
```

Comment: i was doing the same :)  here is a link to play with the above query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15eba/28

Comment: Yeah man! You nailed it! And I am too blind. Thanks for your help!

Comment: nice to hear it helped.