# Get the latest N results for each person

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to build a personalized query for my table which consists on obtaining the latest N records for each person. My table schema is as follows:

```
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| person    | varchar(100)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| time      | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

For example, if I had the following data:

```
+---------+-------+
| person  | time  |
+---------+-------+
| A       | 2     |
| A       | 7     |
| B       | 1     |
| B       | 6     |
| B       | 4     |
| C       | 3     |
+---------+-------+
```

and my `N = 2`, the expected result would be:

```
+---------+-------+
| person  | time  |
+---------+-------+
| A       | 7     |
| A       | 2     |
| B       | 6     |
| B       | 4     |
| C       | 3     |
+---------+-------+
```

(Just last 2 results for each person, order by person asc, time desc)

I know I can get all the person names first and select/order/limit them one by one, but I'm curious to know if I could to this in one query, and let the DBMS do the hard work. For `N = 1`, I successfully used max and group by statements:

```
SELECT person, max(time) as time FROM table GROUP BY person ORDER BY person ASC, time DESC
```

But I don't know how to extend it for greater values of N. Can you please help me?

Comment: looks like duplicate of existing                                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991943/sqlite-how-to-select-first-n-row-of-each-group

Comment: What if the 2nd and 3rd record for 1 user both have the same `time`? Which one to show?

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/q/21257396/247372

Comment: @Rudie forgot to mention that the pair (person, time) is a primary key, not allowing duplication. So it's not possible to have, for example (Z, 2), (Z, 2), and all numbers are integers.

Comment: For those who pointed as duplicate, I think you are right, I didn't know the name of this problem, but the questions look very similar to this one. I will try to find a suitable query for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution using the @Rudie link:

```
select * from (
    select a.* from points as a
    left join points as a2
    on a.person= a2.person and a.time <= a2.time
    group by person, time
    having count(*) <= 2) a
order by person asc, time desc;
```

Live example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58026/2

It's working very well. Thank you all for the contributions!